# How to append HTML to a div whilst still allowing for listeners to work?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following HTML I want to append to a div:

```
var map_div =
"<div class=\"maps\">"
  + "<h2>View marker <button class=\"close\" data-what=\"maps\">[ close ]</button></h2>"
  + "<div class=\"the-contents\" id=\"mapDiv" + link_id + "\"></div>"
+ "</div>";
```

I can do this with:

```
document.getElementById("listing"+link_id).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', map_div );
```

This adds the HTML into the div properly - but there is a problem problem with this, in that it doesn't seem to keep the listeners on **button.close**. This works fine if I put that HTML in directly in the original code (and don't try to to inject it into the DOM). Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to create each individual element, then add it via `appendChild`, and then add another element into that new element? Seems a bit long winded :/

Thanks

Comment: When you add listeners, button actually is not in the DOM, so listener can not be attached to it before you add it to DOM

Comment: Show how you add listeners.

Comment: @MysterX ah man , I fee stupid now! I actually have 2 functions for creating the listeners: `querySelectorLive` (based on https://github.com/FremyCompany/querySelectorLive), and then handleEvent() , which is just a basic "on load" kind of DOM listener. I was using the handleEvent() function instead of `querySelectorLive` ... DUH!!!

Comment: Just an aside, merely replacing `\"` with `'` would already make that code much more readable. Also check template literals. (you can also look at jQuery. `var $button = $("<button>").addClass("close").data("what", "maps").text("[ close ]");`

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the heads up. I always wondered why you couldn't do that in JS (you can do it in Perl using tens of ways). That would certainly clean things up!

Comment: @MysterX that works like a charm now! Please add an answer about either adding a "live" listener so I can accept it.

Comment: @AndrewNewby, sorry, I have no time to compose answer, just wanted to help you to clarify this issue

Comment: @MysterX no worries - I was just wanting you to get some credit for pointing me in the right direction =)

Comment: @ChrisG - I just happened to notice temlate literals don't work in opera-mini or IE 11. What a shame :( https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener to the container and use custom properties to identify the element's role and id:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener(
  "click",
  e=>addItem(++startID)
)

var startID=0;
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const addItem = itemID => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerHTML = `
  <a href="#" data-role="say-hi" data-id="${itemID}">say hi</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="remove" data-id="${itemID}">remove</a>
  ${itemID}
  `;
  el.setAttribute("data-link-container-id",itemID);
  container.appendChild(el);
}

const handleClickable = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const id= e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  console.log("hello:",id);
}
const handleRemove = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const id= e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  container.querySelector(`[data-link-container-id="${id}"]`).remove();
}
//add event listener to container and use data-role to see what's clicked
container.addEventListener(
  "click",
  e=>{
    const role = e.target.getAttribute("data-role");
    if(role==="say-hi"){
      return handleClickable(e);
    }
    if(role==="remove"){
      return handleRemove(e);
    }
  }
)
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button>add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. That seems a bit long winded for what I want to do :) I already have this "live" listener: https://github.com/FremyCompany/querySelectorLive